# Hibernate many-to-many data retrieval, via query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-mapping

Please help me, I think there is something that I am not doing correct.
I have `User` and `Contact`, that are in `Many-to-Many` relation.

User.java:

```
public class User {

    private Integer userID;

    private String userLoginEmail;

    private Set<Contact> contactSet = new HashSet<Contact>();

    public User() {

    }

    .
    getters and setters
    .
```

Contact.java

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private Integer contactID;
    private Set<User> userSet= new HashSet<User>();
    public Contact() {
    }
    .
    getters and setters
    .
    .
```

Mapping for User:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="projectdb">
 <class name="User" table="USERACCOUNT">
  <id column="USER_ID" length="500" name="userID">
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <set cascade="all" fetch="select" lazy="true" name="contactSet"
   sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
   <key column="USER_ID"/>
   <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Contact"
    column="CONTACT_ID" order-by="CONTACT_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapping for Contact:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="projectdb">
 <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
  <id column="CONTACT_ID" length="500" name="contactID">
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <!-- many to many mapping with the User via User_Contact table -->
  <set inverse="true" lazy="false" name="userSet" sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
    <key column="USER_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Contact" column="CONTACT_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am trying to write a query to get the `Contacts` associated with the `User` that is logged in.

When I try to write the following query:

```
Query query=session.createQuery("select contact from com.src.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID");
        query.setParameter("userID", user.getUserID());
        contactList=query.list();
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.src.model.Contact [select contact from com.src.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
```

I know what the error message means, but I am not being able to figure out how to write this query.

First I did like this: [Hibernate many-to-many data retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868868/hibernate-many-to-many-data-retrieval)

but now I am writing a query because I need to check on the `Contact` status, and other parameters.

Thanks
Harbir

This is how I am calling the query:

```
@Override
    public List<Contact> getContactList(User user) {
        log.info("getContactList(User user)");
        List contactList = new ArrayList();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("About to hit the query");
        Query query=session.createQuery("select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID");
        query.setParameter("userID", user.getUserID());
        contactList=query.list();
        return contactList;
    }
```

The following is the stack trace:

```
About to hit the query
18:56:01.011 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID
18:56:01.020 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] 'from'
    |  |  +-[RANGE] 'RANGE'
    |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |  |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] 'com'
    |  |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'smallworks'
    |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'model'
    |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'Contact'
    |  |  |  \-[ALIAS] 'contact'
    |  |  \-[JOIN] 'join'
    |  |     +-[DOT] '.'
    |  |     |  +-[IDENT] 'contact'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] 'userSet'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] 'u'
    |  \-[SELECT] 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] 'contact'
    \-[WHERE] 'where'
       \-[EQ] '='
          +-[DOT] '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] 'u'
          |  \-[IDENT] 'userID'
          \-[COLON] ':'
             \-[IDENT] 'userID'

18:56:01.020 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
18:56:01.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
18:56:01.050 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.smallworks.model.Contact (contact) -> contact0_
18:56:01.051 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  contact -> contact0_.CONTACT_ID
18:56:01.053 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : userSet -> org.hibernate.type.SetType(com.smallworks.model.Contact.userSet)
18:56:01.053 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory - createManyToMany() : path = contact.userSet role = com.smallworks.model.Contact.userSet associatedEntityName = com.smallworks.model.Contact
18:56:01.055 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.smallworks.model.Contact (u) -> contact2_
18:56:01.055 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause - addJoinByPathMap() : contact.userSet -> smallworksdb.CONTACT contact2_
18:56:01.055 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode - dereferenceCollection() : Created new FROM element for contact.userSet : smallworksdb.USER_CONTACT contact2_
18:56:01.055 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  contact.userSet -> .
18:56:01.056 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - createFromJoinElement() : -- join tree --
 \-[JOIN_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'smallworksdb.USER_CONTACT contact2_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=u,role=com.smallworks.model.Contact.userSet,tableName=smallworksdb.CONTACT,tableAlias=contact2_,origin=smallworksdb.CONTACT contact0_,colums={contact0_.CONTACT_ID ,className=com.smallworks.model.Contact}}

18:56:01.056 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  contact -> contact0_.CONTACT_ID
18:56:01.060 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  u -> contact2_.CONTACT_ID
18:56:01.060 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.smallworks.controller.ProjectController@1f183871]: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.smallworks.model.Contact [select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
18:56:01.062 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.smallworks.controller.ProjectController@1f183871]: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.smallworks.model.Contact [select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
18:56:01.062 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.smallworks.controller.ProjectController@1f183871]: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.smallworks.model.Contact [select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
18:56:01.069 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.smallworks.model.Contact [select contact from com.smallworks.model.Contact  contact join contact.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:61) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1385) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.toType(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1457) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:302) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:407) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:589) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:211) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:750) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1216) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4041) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3525) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1762) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:776) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:577) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:251) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at com.smallworks.dao.impl.ContactDAOImpl.getContactList(ContactDAOImpl.java:92) [ContactDAOImpl.class:na]
    at com.smallworks.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.getContactList(ContactServiceImpl.java:95) [ContactServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.smallworks.controller.ProjectController.addContact(ProjectController.java:117) [ProjectController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
18:56:01.069 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.o.h.s.OpenSessionInViewFilter - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
18:56:01.069 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'check on the Contact status'?

Comment: By 'check on the Contact status' I mean,  that I need to get Contacts based on their status. I know we can do either by query or criteria. I am trying to do with query and its not working.

Comment: I don't understand how getting this error message is even possible, since your query doesn't try to access a property userId of Contact. Are you sure you deployed the right code, and pasted the exact error message?

Comment: @JBNizet, I have posted the full stack trace, yes, I have deployed the correct code and pasted the correct error message.

Comment: Why are you not just saying `user.getContactSet()`?

Comment: @TomAnderson, I think, I can do this way, but this way I will first be fetching all the Contacts and checking which ones I need. Don't you think it will be much faster if we use the Criteria, or Query to fetch the ones we need, rather than fetching all and then checking? Its mentioned in the discussion below.

Comment: @Harbir, it really depends. Are there many contacts per user? How often do you execute this query? Hibernate is a trade-off, you sacrifice some performance to receive the object orientation benefits.

Comment: There are about more than 1000 contacts person, and when the user logs in there will be all his contacts displayed to him. So this is used quite often.

Comment: @JBNizet I have made some progress, But I need the contacts with status 40, and I am still getting ALL the Contacts. Query query=session.createQuery("select distinct u.contactSet FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u INNER JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userIDPara AND c.contactStatus=:contactStatusPara"); query.setParameter("userIDPara", user.getUserID()); query.setParameter("contactStatusPara", 40); contactList=query.list(); Its giving me all the contacts, and not just the ones with the status 40.

Comment: It should be `select distinct c ...`

Comment: Great Thanks @JBNizet, you and Yori really helped me resolve this, but I still do not understand why was it looking for userID on Contact. Yori, suggested that could be a caching issue. I will try to run this whole many-to-many relation via main, rather than via web-app, that I am doing now.

Comment: @Harbir: The code in your question is simply retrieving all contacts for a user, so it's exactly equivalent to `user.getContactSet()`. I see from your comments on one of the answers that you are adding a further condition, in which case sure, you may be better off doing this as a query.

Answer (score 2):

In the XML mapping Contact, the mapping of userSet is completely wrong:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="projectdb">
 <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
  <!-- ... --->
  <set inverse="true" lazy="false" name="userSet" sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
    <key column="USER_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Contact" column="CONTACT_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It should be:

```
  <set inverse="true" lazy="false" name="userSet" sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
    <key column="CONTACT_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.User" column="USER_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>
```

It looks to me like you copy-and-pasted this from User and then didn't update it.

Why are you using XML rather than annotations? XML is much more error-prone, as you can see. In addition, a lot of these settings should be defaulted correctly by Hibernate. If you had just left out some of these attributes, it probably would have worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood right. You want to "get the Contacts associated with the User that is logged in." "I need to check on the Contact status...", correct?

If that is the case, try writing the query the other way around. So, you can start with the same query you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868868/hibernate-many-to-many-data-retrival/15870473?noredirect=1#comment25731795_15870473) . Let's suppose you want "All contacts with status 'ACTIVE' for the User that is logged in".

```
// First, retrieve the user you want.
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user_id_you_want);
// Return only the conctats with status 'ACTIVE' 
List result = new ArrayList();
for(Contact c : contacts){
  if(c.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")){
    result.add(c);
  }
}
return result;
```

I hope it helps...

**===UPDATE1===**

You are right, I thought a user would have a few contacts. How about if you try something like:

```
"FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u LEFT JOIN u.contacts as c WHERE u.userId=:userId AND c.status=:status"
```

Note that you may start your statement with "FROM" instead of "SELECT". See some good examples in this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm).

Another important reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Additionally, note that in your case the class User owns the relationship, some statements need to take the ownership in consideration.

Comment: I think, I can do this way, but this way I will first be fetching all the Contacts and checking which ones I need.
Don't you think it will be much faster if we use the Criteria, or Query to fetch the ones we need, rather than fetching all and then checking?

Comment: I have tried the following

Query query=session.createQuery("FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u LEFT JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userID");
  query.setParameter("userID", user.getUserID());
  contactList=query.list();
but this way I am getting the list of Objects and not Contacts, When I try to iterate through the list, its complaining about the casting. Any idea?

Comment: You need to cast it to User instead of Contact. This user contains the contacts you are looking for.

Comment: I just noticed that you have a bidirectional relationship. What happens if you use this HQL (casting it to Contact): FROM com.src.model.Contact c INNER JOIN c.userSet u WHERE u.userID=:userID

Comment: I tried "from com.smallworks.model.Contact  c INNER JOIN c.userSet u where u.userID=:userID"

it starts giving Exception for userID on Contact

10:39:17.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of: com.smallworks.model.Contact [from com.smallworks.model.Contact  c INNER JOIN c.userSet u where u.userID=:userID]
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]

Comment: When I try casting like:
Query query=session.createQuery("FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u LEFT JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userID");
  query.setParameter("userID", user.getUserID());
  userList=query.list();
  User userDB=userList.get(0);
  List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
  Object[] objtArray= userDB.getContactSet().toArray();
  contactList=Arrays.asList(objtArray);

I get:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.smallworks.model.User
 at com.smallworks.dao.impl.ContactDAOImpl.getContactList(ContactDAOImpl.java:97)

Comment: You should not get "Could not complete request org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userID of...". If you are running in a web app it is possible to have some weird cache. How about if you create a simple main class (or JUnit) and run it from there?

Comment: Hi, based on your original query, I have made some progress, But I need the contacts with status 40, and I am still getting ALL the Contacts. 
Query query=session.createQuery("select distinct u.contactSet FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u INNER JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userIDPara AND c.contactStatus=:contactStatusPara");
  query.setParameter("userIDPara", user.getUserID());
  query.setParameter("contactStatusPara", 40);
  contactList=query.list();

Its giving me all the contacts, and not just the ones with the status 40.

Comment: Thanks @Yori, you and JBnizet really helped me resolve this, but I still do not understand why was it looking for userID on Contact. You, suggested that could be a caching issue. I will try to run this whole many-to-many relation via main, rather than via web-app, that I am doing now.
I am using the following query: select distinct c FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u INNER JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userIDPara AND c.contactStatus=:contactStatusPara . Please update your answer accordingly, so as I am mark it as answered :)

Comment: @Harbir, this thread is getting too long and hard to read. How about if you create a small app where you can recreate your issue? Next, create a new SO thread; so, we can help you better.